# AWS Lambda trigger on a new partition being added into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an S3 bucket `A` on which a Glue Catalog is defined which reads date from key `foo/bar/` and is partitioned on `date`.

example:
`s3://A/foo/bar/baz/date=2020-01-30`

Data comes randomly to this bucket.

I need to add missing partitions to the Glue table, as and when new partitions are uploaded to this bucket.

I can do this using lambda which will run an MSCK REPAIR TABLE

How do I trigger this lambda when a new partition `date` has been uploaded to s3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no concept of a partition or directory in Amazon S3**. The filename (`Key`) of an object includes the full path of the object.

Therefore, there is no way to know that the partition was 'created'.

However... Amazon S3 recognizes the 'creation' of a directory when a **zero-length object** is created with the name of the directory. This forces the directory to 'appear' in the Amazon S3 management console. **If** the system that is creating the partition is also creating this zero-length object, then this could be used to recognize the creation of a partition.

To do so, the AWS Lambda function would need to look at the object that was created (passed through the `event` field from the Amazon S3 Event) and determine whether it is a zero-length object. If so, it could trigger the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`.

You would need to explore the existing directory structure to see whether the current process is creating these zero-length files. (Frankly, it probably isn't.)

The only remaining method would be to **use a database to keep track of the existing partitions**. Then, the Lambda function could consult the database to see whether an object is being created in a "new partition". If so, it should update the database, then trigger the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`. The database could even be as simple as an entry in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store.